# bind combobox to one table and save the values in other table in winform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am very new to c# and visual studio

In my winform application , i have two table as data source :

1. Entry form
2. Master rejection reason

Now i need to fetch the rejection reason from one table and save the same on the entry form table ,Now when i bind these combo box to the rejreason table by creating a binding source , all the three combo boxes are updating with same value , and irrespective of the ID number where my entry is doing it is starting to save from the first row only , for example if Idon't enter the rej reason for first two rows and if i enter the rej reason for third row , the data is getting saved for 1st row only , kindly help me how to solve this , and kindly ask me if anything else is needed..

the design can be seen in attached images:
[Rej reason form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIqyD.png)

[image: Dataset.Xsd]

[image: Entry form]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, call [`DataTable.Copy Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.copy?view=net-5.0) to get a datatable copy and use it as the datasource of the comboboxes.

```
// ds.Tables[0] is the RejReason Table
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Reason";
comboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Reason"; 
comboBox3.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Reason";
```